# can't open some of the chrome extension files for debugging, they aren't shown in "sources" tag

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to run rikaikun in debugger, to see how it works and to stole some code later. I opened `chrome://extensions/`, clicked `inspect views: background.html`, this opened devtools. I want to place a breakpoint in rikaicontent.js, but in the "sources" tab there is only files "background.html", "data.js" and "rikaichan.js". File rikaicontent.js exists in folder, and is methoned in manifest.json, but devtools can't see them. Why? How to place this breakpoint?

Comment: By the file name, it's probably a content script. You'll find it in the dev tools of the regular webpages where it is injected. Go to "Sources", and inside that select the "Content Scripts" tab.

Comment: @rsanchez yes, it's there, thank you.